# How to set reminder that repeats only on weekdays?

Tags: applications, 4.4-kitkat, calendar

How to set reminder that repeats only on weekdays(except saturday and sunday) on Android(kitkat) calendar app?

Comment: What calendar app do you use?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning that!. Its Calendar snooze app. It extends the standard andorid calendar.                                                                                  [ https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bitfire.development.calendarsnooze&hl=en ]

Comment: It is not a calendar app as I see. It just gives you more options for alert systems. Go to the calendar app and choose option "Repeat every weekday". It is available on (almost) every calendar app.

Comment: Thank you Alex... the problem was that i accidentaly set the repeat event from a date in the past during which the weekday option is absent....